# How to save values of json fields in a list using Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following `JSON` structure:

```
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "UserName": "Administrator",  
            "CreateDate": "2018-01-26T13:07:28Z", 
            "UserId": "YYYYY", 
        }, 
        {
            "UserName": "test_user1", 
            "CreateDate": "2018-01-26T14:32:13Z", 
            "UserId": "XXXXX", 
        }, 
    ]
}
```

I read this file this way:

```
jsonIAMUsers = open('reports/1.16-IAM.json', 'r')
IAMUsers = json.load(jsonIAMUsers)
jsonIAMUsers.close()
```

Ho do I save the values of every `UserName` field into a list in order to iterate over it? I mean how can I put `Administrator` and `test_user1` in a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)!

```
with open('reports/1.16-IAM.json') as jsonIAMUsers:
    IAMUsers = json.load(jsonIAMUsers)
usernames = [u['UserName'] for u in IAMUsers['Users']]
```

Note `with` part. It is [context manager](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html), which will do all file-related routine(close, etc) for you.

Default mode for `open` function is `r`, so it might be skipped.

Comment: @Rusanov It gives me the following error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: @Riccardo, my bad, fixed now.